# Magento type theme setup in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

How can we setup multiple themes in codeigniter as in Magento?

I want to do this in HMVC CI.
I want to add theming feature with my development. I am using HMVC setup from [Codeigniter HMVC](https://github.com/johnrich85/Codeigniter-HMVC-login-script)

This is properly set and works fine.
This is a great development approach.
Here I am trying to add theme feature with this code, that could be controlled from admin panel.

```
/themes/themeName/templates/   
/themes/themeName/modulesName/View
```

Approach is if view file not found in themes folder, it should come from

```
application/modules/moduleName.
```

What changes I have to do with this script ?

Can anyone suggest me what modification nee to do with this code?

Comment: Is there any one who could guide for this?

Comment: I'm afraid what you're asking is too broad, It's litteraly asking someone to write a significant piece of code. While I'm working on something similar that i'll publish soon, I don't think you'll get your answer here, Unless someone has a pre made solution that he's willing to share.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I misunderstood but why not extend CI's Loader class and add a theme function? I did this recently and it works great.

```
public function theme($view, $theme, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE) {

    // Check if extension was specified. If not, add .php
    $ext = pathinfo(APPPATH . $theme, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $view_file = ($ext == '') ? $view.'.php' : $view;

    // Verify whether or not the requested theme file exists and set the template directory path prefix accordingly
    if(file_exists(APPPATH . "views/store/theme/$theme/$view_file")) {
        $this->_ci_view_paths = array(APPPATH . "views/store/theme/$theme/" => true);
    }
    else {
        $this->_ci_view_paths = array(APPPATH . "views/store/theme/default/" => true);
    }

    return $this->_ci_load(array('_ci_view' => $view, '_ci_vars' => $this->_ci_object_to_array($vars), '_ci_return' => $return));
}
```

Comment: I defined theme() in CI's Loader, now how to use this function? How to call in controller instead of load view

Comment: views/store/theme here you have created theme folder inside module. I think modules should come inside theme folder. views/theme/$theme/store . What do you think?

Comment: It's quite simple, you just call $this->load->theme() like you would view(), but with the slightly different parameters: the view file, the name of the theme (theme directory), your data array and boolean for return or direct display. It will look for the view requested and if found, use it, otherwise use the corresponding view from the default theme.

Comment: The key here is "$this->_ci_view_paths". This tells CI's Loader where to look for view files.